# HP-UX 10.20 software depots

Tags: hp-ux

I've been looking for HP-UX 9.X and 10.20 patches and it looks like I'm late to the party. I found the original FTP sites from HP have all been taken down. I'm sure that someone must have made a complete mirror of these materials. I would have done it had I been paying attention at the time. I'm a younger UNIX geek hoping that an old timer can help me out here.

Does anyone know where to find backups of all the old HP-UX 10.20 software depots and patches?

For example I found this:
ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software1/wk122/wk122en

But I can't find the catalog of what else is on this FTP server...

NOTE: I've learned that these depots may have never been officially posted on-line. What I am looking for might be .ISOs of the CDs that were sent out to people who had a support contract at the time of release. If you have CDs like this please make backups. CDs don't last forever.

Comment: This might help: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/hp/hpux-faq/

Comment: Crumbs.  HP-UX 10.20 support ended 14 years ago!  You're trying to fix a (very) leaky tap.

Comment: People keep all sorts of old things around for all sorts of reasons. I found a group who has live AMIGA machines! I love old technology.

Comment: I think 10.20 is still under a license. Last patch bundle were issued for Y2K compliance,  perhaps you could check archive.org, or abandon-ware sites.

Answer (score 2):

Other than getting a list of patches (eg, from HP documentation) and searching for them, your best option may be to get in contact with classic computing enthusiasts.

I can suggest the following:

1. [ClassicCmp](http://classiccmp.org/) [mailing list](http://classiccmp.org/lists.html)
2. [SunHELP](http://www.sunhelp.org/) [Rescue mailing list](http://www.sunhelp.org/mailman/listinfo/rescue)
3. [The Unix Heritage Society](http://www.tuhs.org/)